# Adding items into a ListView in a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I want to add items in  ListView through an editText, but when i run my code, it dosn't work.

```
public class EventosFragment extends Fragment {
private ListView lista;
private Button boton;
EditText editText;
ArrayList<String> arrayList;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_eventos, container, false);

    String[] Lista = {};
    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.Lista);
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Lista));
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edittxt);
    Button btnAdd = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Aceptar);
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String Aceptar = editText.getText().toString();
            arrayList.add(Aceptar);
        }
    });

    return view;
}
}
```

Any suggestions will do, i'm new in Java, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `notifyDataSetChanged` in `onclick` method. Your data is successfully added in arraylist but your adapter doesn't know about it you have notify the adapter. Just like this

```
 arrayList.add(Aceptar);
 //this will notify the adapter whole is changed
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: This is not proper answer as adapter.notifyItemInserted(arrayList.size()-1) is not method of ArrayAdapter, Please check again.

Comment: @NehalGodhasara You did the same thing in your posted answer.

Comment: I think you haven't noticed this answer is edited later, and I posted same answer before this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use notifyDataSetChanged() method of adapter after adding item to arraylist.

```
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String Aceptar = editText.getText().toString();
            arrayList.add(Aceptar);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Hope it will help!!